# How to self-host production Next.js app via HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, next.js, https

We’re a small organization with decent on-prem hardware, I have a virtual server and plan to build a dashboard app which will interactively display some data from a Pocketbase db on the same server.

However, I can’t find any info on how to serve the NextJS app via HTTPS using our own SSL certificates. Our provider is GoDaddy so I guess I’d have to obtain a new certificate for a new subdomain, but how do I install it and serve the app via HTTPS? I want to open the app to the public so third parties can also access it.

I don’t want to host it in the cloud as I have plenty of hardware resources on-prem and I don’t want to use Docker as I get no benefits from it.

Comment: "Our provider is GoDaddy" — What are they providing if you want to host on-prem?

Comment: @Quentin He's talking about the certificate he wants to install since they also provide SSL certificates.

Comment: @Quentin indeed we use them for our SSL certificates and other stuff but I don’t want to host my app with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did it using Certbot and Nginx on my Windows 11 home machine and it's super easy.

So here's how to run a local any NodeJS app on Windows, using nginx for reverse proxy and serve it over HTTPS using Certbot. All you need is your own domain.

1. Download & extract [Nginx for Windows](https://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html)
2. Run PowerShell as admin in directory and run `start nginx`
3. Run `tasklist /fi "imagename eq nginx.exe"` to see it running
4. Start the NextJS or other app, on port 5173 for example
5. Edit `nginx.conf` and change the HTTP section. On Linux edit `default` in `./sites-enabled`:

```
        server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  sub.domain.com;

            location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5173;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

This will create a reverse proxy to the local app on port 5173. Test the site on HTTP

6. Install [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=windows)
7. Stop nginx
8. Run Powershell as admin and run `certbot certonly --standalone`
9. Follow instructions and the certificate will be downloaded in `C:\Certbot\archive`
10. Edit `nginx.conf` and change the HTTPS section:

```
        server {
               listen       443 ssl;
               server_name  sub.domain.com;
               ssl_certificate      C:\Certbot\archive\sub.domain.com\cert1.pem;
               ssl_certificate_key  C:\Certbot\archive\sub.domain.com\privkey1.pem;
    …
        
        location / {
                   proxy_pass http://localhost:5173;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
               }
```

11. Restart nginx. App should be accesible via HTTPS
12. Edit `nginx.conf` and change the HTTP section for automatic redirect to HTTPS, if needed:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  sub.domain.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5173;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

13. Restart nginx again after any `nginx.conf` change

Comment: Good answer but why prefer the certificates in `archive` instead of `live`?

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan for some reason that’s where my nginx put the certificates.

Comment: I see, well, I can confirm that it works with the `live` directory as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider a [reverse-proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) using something like NGINX. This will allow you to [install your GoDaddy SSL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-and-configure-nginx-web-server-on-godaddy-vps-ubuntu/) certificate on the web server that proxies all incoming requests to your Next.js instance and returns the response.

Comment: this seems to be the consensus from what I’ve found. 

Do you have any idea if the proxy interferes with the hybrid nature of Next.js, i.e. with the state transfer between server and client components?

Comment: Does not impose any issues whatsoever. Since requests and responses are just being tunneled between the two servers. Also have a setup running like that in production.